# foreach delegate in QML TreeView

Tags: qml

Similar to [Foreach delegate in QML view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29329575/foreach-delegate-in-qml-view) I'm having trouble finding a list of current delegates in a QML `TreeView`.

However, the actual problem I'm trying to solve is this: I have a C++ class that inherits from `QAbstractItemModel` that provides several different roles.  One of them is `Qt::CheckStateRole` which functions as an indicator for whether a particular item in the `TreeView` is selected for display elsewhere in the GUI.

Using [Edit QStandardItemModel via TableView with Custom Delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49529314/edit-qstandarditemmodel-via-tableview-with-custom-delegate) as a general guide (but adapted to `TreeView`, hint: use `mapToItem()` instead of `mapFromGlobal()`) I'm able to service user clicks to the checkbox that appears in that particular column (role).  However, I need to programmatically alter the state of other checkboxes as well (different than the one that got clicked).

Strangely, `dataChanged()` signals (got them working for all of the other roles) do not affect the state of the checkbox (this is Qt 5.12.2, Ubuntu 20.04).  I know what state I want to impose on the checkbox, and of course I should only need to do that for the currently existing delegates.  However, it seems like it ought to be extremely convoluted -- the way there's a separate delegate for each role -- on top of the hierarchal nature of the data.

So, is there a way to access the set of currently existing delegates for a particular role that is operative in a QML TreeView?

Comment: I don't recommend trying to directly access the items of a view. Iterate over the model instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to iterate over delegates I found that instead I could just create a `Connections` component within the delegate that connects a global `youNeedToUpdateYourValue()` signal to the delegate, which reassesses the current state of the checkbox.  As the connection will disappear when the delegate is pruned, this seems to be a very elegant way to impose an action upon all existing delegates.